# Facebook SDK for Android gives wrong result for cover picture

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an app that uses Facebook for user login purposes. That process is succesfully completed, but when I ask Facebook for user's information (with the corresponding permissions), I get everything but his cover picture. The response I always get is a "FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT" and a JFIF image with error code 200, instead of the expected response of a JSON object with the image's URL, like this:

```
[{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT":"����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000��\u0000\u0004*\u0000��\u0002\u001cICC_PROFILE\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0002"}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}]
```

I tested the app's access token at Graph API Explorer in Facebook's developer page, and it worked there. This issue only happens in the device, so I have no clue of where the problem may be.

I changed app's permissions recently. However, the app has been running perfectly with the new permissions until today, where the response suddenly changed to that JFIF image. If anybody could give me any indications or solutions for this problem, I'd be really grateful.

EDIT: Here is the part of the source code:

```
public void getImage(String image_id, int width, int height)
{

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    // Get request parameters
    Bundle requestParams = new Bundle();
    requestParams.putString("access_token", session.getAccessToken());
    requestParams.putBoolean("redirect", false);
    requestParams.putInt("width", width);
    requestParams.putInt("height", height);

    // Request URL
    String requestURL = "/" + image_id + "/picture";

    Request request = new Request(session, requestURL, requestParams, HttpMethod.GET, callback);

    Response response = request.executeAndWait();
    if (response.getError() == null)
    {
        setResponseJSON(response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject());
    }
}
```

Comment: which facebook sdk you are using?

Comment: Facebook Android 3.0. I'll check if an update is available.

Comment: Updated to SDK 3.0.2, but the issue still happens.

Comment: can you put some code, so we can also debug it

Comment: added the source code... hope it helps

Comment: I am getting the proper response, used your code :) Why are you using `executeAndWait()`, you should probably use `executeAsync();` and the check the response in the callback's `onComplete` method

Comment: This method is called from an AsyncTask, so the execution is not blocked... that's why I'm using executeAndWait(). I also made it work from Facebook developer's page, that's why I can't understand why it's not working now :(. Maybe it's an issue related to permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an async class for getting the users facebook. The only thing you need is the Facebook user id.

private class SetUserFacebookImage extends AsyncTask {

```
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Retrieving Facebook profile image...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        String urlStr = params[0];
        Bitmap img = null;

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlStr);
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = (HttpResponse)client.execute(request);           
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedHttpEntity bufferedEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
            InputStream inputStream = bufferedEntity.getContent();
            img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);       
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(FRAGMENT_NAME, "INVALID URL");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(FRAGMENT_NAME, "UNABLE TO PARSE FACEBOOK IMAGE");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

        return img;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        if(bitmap != null) {
            mUserProfileImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            mUser.setProfile_picture(mImageAdapter.encodeBitmap(bitmap));
        } else
            mUserProfileInterface.relayUserValidationError(
                    getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_unable_to_get_user_profile));
    }
}
```

You can call the task like this:

```
new SetUserFacebookImage().execute(new String[] {getFacebookUserURL(mUser.getFace_book_id())});
```